# their representation is part of their definition as related to C++ concrete types?

Tags: c++, c++11

In both of his books

*The C++ Programming Language*, 2013 (4th edition) and
*A Tour of C++*, 2013

Bjarne Stroustrup writes:

> **Types** such as complex ... **are called concrete types** **because
>   their representation is part of their definition**.

What follows to some extent clarifies the above statement:

> In that, they resemble built-in types. In contrast, an abstract type
>   is a type that completely  insulates  a  user  from  implementation 
>   details. To  do that,  we  decouple  the  interface from the
>   representation and give up genuine local variables.  Since we don’t
>   know anything about the representation of an abstract type (not even
>   its size), we must allocate objects on the free store and access them
>   through references or pointers.

---

## Questions

In the phrase *"...their representation is part of their definition."*

1. What is the meaning of **type representation**? That is, the representation of what exactly: The object layout in memory? The private and public data that the type holds? Or something else?
2. What is the meaning of **type definition**?
3. Are these typical meanings of type representation and definition as related to C++?

---

I decided to do some more research and I checked other sources. First I looked through ISO/IEC 14882:2011 specifications that state requirements for implementations of the C++ programming language, then through other sources.

### Ad question 1

I was not able to find in ISO specs anything like "type representation" or "representation of a type". Instead there are 2 terms related to objects:

> The **object representation** of an object of type `T` is the sequence of *N* `unsigned char` objects taken up by the object of type `T`, where *N* equals `sizeof(T)`.
>
> The **value representation of an object** is the set of bits that hold the value of type `T`. For trivially copyable types, the value representation is a set of bits in the object representation that determines a value, which is one discrete element of an implementation-defined set of values.

So it seems to me that the term *type representation* does not have any conventional meaning within the ISO standards.

Ok. Maybe it is something outside the ISO standards? Let's see what
[Linux Standard Base C++ Specification 3.1 > Chapter 7. C++ Class Representations > 7.1. C++ Data Representation](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/LSB_3.1.0/LSB-CXX-generic/LSB-CXX-generic/cxxclasses.html) says:

> An object file generated by the compilation process for a C++ program shall contain several closely related **internal objects, or Class Components**, to **represent each C++ Class**. Such objects are not a visible part of the source code. The following table describes these Class Components at a high level.
>
> **Table Class Components**
>
> ```
> Object.......................Contains
> =----------------------------------------=
> Class Data...................Class members
> Virtual Table................Information needed to dispatch virtual functions,
>                              access virtual base class subobjects and to access
>                              the RTTI information
> RTTI.........................Run-Time Type Information used by the typeid and
>                              dynamic_cast operators, and exception handlers
> Typeinfo Name................String representation of Class name
> Construction Virtual Table...Information needed during construction and
>                              destruction of Classes with non-trivial
>                              inheritance relationships.
> VTT..........................A table of virtual table pointers which holds the
>                              addresses of construction and non-construction
>                              virtual tables.
> ```

### Ad question 2

I was again not able to find in ISO specs an explicit explanation of **type definition**.

Instead I found the following:

> A **declaration** may introduce one or more names into a translation
>   unit... A **class declaration** introduces the class name into the
>   scope where it is declared...**A declaration is a deﬁnition unless**
>   [I removed things not directly related to the class declaration], ...
>   **it is a class name declaration**...

Here is a Microsoft interpretation of the same thing:

> [C++ Declarations - MSDN - Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/0kw7hsf3)
>
> A **declaration** introduces
>   one or more names into a program. Declarations can occur more than
>   once in a program...**Declarations also serve as definitions, except
>   when the declaration**:...;**Is a class name declaration with no
>   following definition, such as class T**;...

and

> [C++ Definitions - MSDN - Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/9e2zdck2)
>
> A **definition** is a unique
>   specification of an object or variable, function, class, or
>   enumerator. Because definitions must be unique, a program can contain
>   only one definition for a given program element. **There can be a
>   many-to-one correspondence between declarations and definitions.**
>   **There are two cases in which a program element can be declared and not defined**: A function is declared but never referenced with a
>   function call or with an expression that takes the function's address.
>   A class is used only in a way that does not require its definition be
>   known.

Examples:

```
struct S;    // declares, but not defines S
class T {};  // declares, and defines T
class P { int a;};  // declares, and defines P, P::a
```

### Conclusions:

**Candidate Answer N1:**
proposed by Jonathan Wakely
(below is my understanding)
The phrase "**Types** such as complex ... **are called concrete types because their representation is part of their definition**" should be interpreted and understood in the following way:
● **their(=type) definition** is a technical c++ term whose meaning is conventional and can be found in c++ specs;
● **their(=type) representation** is (according to Jonathan Wakely) not a technical c++ term in this context, but its meaning can be easily figured out by anybody who understands English language well enough (and probably, it is my guess, has been previously exposed to the generous amount of c++ codes and texts). Type representation in this context means 
"the properties that define what the type is and what it does", that is:
"for a concrete type: the type and layout of its members",
"for an abstract type: its member functions and their observable behavior"
● The whole phrase then (we are talking about the concrete classes) translates to:
"**Types** such as complex ... **are called concrete types because the types and layouts of their members are part of their definition**"
I think this interpretation makes sense, is understandable, and also agrees well with what follows it in the BS books.

Please correct me if something here is not ok**

Comment: The *definition* of a class contains the specification of its base classes and data members.

Comment: Means their memory representation, i.e. their layout.

Comment: "In many important cases, such as `vector`, that representation is only one or more pointers to more data stored elsewhere [...]" TC++PL 3.2.1 -- So I think "representation" refers to data members, not necessarily the specific object memory layout in some specific implementation.

Comment: Reading TC++PL in the way you would read standardese is a bad idea.

Comment: I'd like to try to improve the formatting a bit, are you still editing the content?

Answer (score 3):

> QUESTIONS: in the phrase **"...their representation is part of their definition."** 1) What is the meaning of **type representation**? (that is, the representation of WHAT exactly: object layout in memory or private and public data that the type holds OR something else) 2) What is the meaning of **type definition**? 3) Are these typical meanings of type representation and definition as related to c++?

You're asking for the meaning of terms that Stroustrup doesn't use in the text you quoted!

He's not trying to define a formal specification of a term like "type representation" the way the C++ standard does, he's writing prose that is more informal. All the references to technical terms that you've dug up are misleading and not directly relevant.

> (that is, the representation of WHAT exactly: object layout in memory or private and public data that the type holds OR something else)

Yes, both the things you mention. For a concrete type the properties that define what it is and what it does include the type and layout of its members. i.e. how it is represented in the source code.

For an abstract class, the properties that define what it is and what it does are its member functions and their observable behaviour. The details of how it produces that observable behaviour are not necessarily important, and sometimes aren't even visible in the source code because you actually use some concrete class defined in another piece of code and only use it through an abstract interface.

**Edit:** Judging from the comments you wrote below you apparently missed that I tried to give you an answer. What I wrote above refers to **the properties that define what a type is and what it does**. That is a "definition of a type".

If you had to write documentation for a C++ type for users, how would you *define* it?

For a concrete type you might describe the types of its members and so define some of its properties in terms of the properties of its members. e.g. "A `std::complex<float>` stores two `float` members, which represent the real and imaginary parts of the complex number." This tells you that `std::complex<float>` can only store complex numbers with the same precision as `float`, i.e. its precision is determined by the fact it is represented using two `float` members.

For an abstract class you would describe the behaviour of its member functions, which are likely to be `virtual`, so you describe it in terms of the interface it follows, not in terms of the details of its implementation.

But they are not formal terms, I think you are wrong to treat them as strict technical terms. He's just using the words with their usual English meaning.

Comment: *"You're asking for the meaning of terms that Stroustrup doesn't use in the text you quoted!"* Although Stroustrup doesn't use the term *type representation*, he talks about the *representation of a type*. Do you mean that he's not using "type representation" as a technical term here?

Comment: (1) "You're asking for the meaning of terms that Stroustrup doesn't use in the text you quoted!". He talks about types: "Types...are called concrete types because their representation is part of their definition." Whose representation? Representation of A TYPE. Whose definition? Defenition of A TYPE.

Comment: (continued from the above comment)
He does not define these terms in his text. So, what am I supposed to do then? He suggests: "For the final word on language definition issues, see the ISO C++ standard". This is what I did. No complains. Still "...their representation is part of their definition" has NO explicit meaning to me.

Comment: (continued from the above comment)
(2) I am preparing for a technical interview.I consider it a likely possibility that an interviewer will ask me something like: "Hey. Let's talk about some basics. Explain me please for what kind of types =their representation is part of their definition=?, and what it really means? "What am I supposed to answer? That it is just some "peace of prose"? And in fact there is nothing like "type representation" in ISO C++ specs, but my guess is the following, and explain my interpretation. I do not think I will pass in a technical interview beyond this point.

Comment: (continued from the above comment)
I am asking my questions because "TC++PL" is a reference text now. And because of that, I believe, everything in it should either have some technical meaning or if it is not, it is the author and editors error/mistake and it has to be corrected. I still hope that somebody can explain me how “a type representation can be part of its definition”. And what are the explicit meanings of representation and definition are in this case. Thanks

Comment: @dyp, yes, doesn't the paragraph immediately after the text you quoted say that?

Comment: @yus, I think you need to read what Stroustrup wrote if you want to understand what he means, he's not using formal definitions that you can look up in the standard. You are wrong to claim that everything in it must have a strict technical meaning or it must be corrected. Anyway, read my answer again: _For a concrete type **the properties that define what it is and what it does** include the type and layout of its members. i.e. how it is represented in the source code._ Here the **definition of a type** means its distinguishing features, its properties, the things you would document about it.

Comment: _"For the final word on language definition issues, see the ISO C++ standard"_ That means **C++ language definition issues**. But you also need to be able to understand English language terms.

Comment: @ Jonathan Wakely If I assume that the meaning of "definition / representation of a type" or "type definition / representation", as used in programming and in particular in a c++ text, is something that follows from regular English language usage, then it must be explained in a regular English language dictionary like say "Webster's Dictionary and Thesaurus" or the like. And obviously it is not there.

Comment: The words "definition" and "representation" are defined in any dictionary. Do you struggle if some says "the rules of football" because your dictionary only has the words "rules" and "football" but doesn't define what "the rules of football" means?

Comment: @ Jonathan Wakely (continied from above) On the other hand, if I assume as you suggested above, that "type representation" =(according to regular English usage)= "class variables/members". Then the phrase "their representation is part of their definition" translates to something like "variables/members of a class are part of that class definition". This makes much more sence and sounds much less misterious =). Still how should I know that in fact 
"type representation" =(according to regular English usage)= "class variables/members"? Should I look it up somewhere? Where? Should I guess?

Comment: It's just [reading comprehension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reading_comprehension), which does require some level of familiarity with the subject matter. But in general Stroustrup's book can be read on its own, without additional texts. In this specific case you don't need any other reference, you already quoted the context he gives to explain the terms, but I think you got distracted trying to find meaning elsewhere instead of studying the book itself and trying to grok what it was saying.

Answer (score 3):

You go looking out for a `vegetable` in dinner tonight. Wait.. a vegetable? The word vegetable defines something for sure but it carries no representation. Someone will surely ask you which vegetable. So a vegetable is an **abstract** concept.

So now you order some `potatoes` and `onions`. Well, they **define** some properties and **represent** themselves well enough so that you can **locate** them in the store. Potatoes and onions make up for **concrete** representation of a type with a well defined property and behavior.

Try writing two classes following this analogy. You may connect to what is meant by `representation is part of their definition.`

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled over the same passage in the text, and it took me a while, but I believe I deduced from the text what is meant by *representation* and *definition* of a class.

**Answer to question 1:** The *representation* of a type are the data members. Those are the members of the type which store the information/state, as opposed to the methods/operations on them.

**Answer to question 2:** The *definition* is simply the code implementing the class. (like the definition of `Vector` below).

**Rationale:** See section 2.3.2 of the same book and pay close attention on the use of the word 'representation':

> Having the **data** specified separately from the operations on it has advantages, such as the ability to use the data in arbitrary ways. However, a tighter connection between the **representation** and the operations is needed for a user-defined type to have all the properties expected of a "real type."

It seems that "representation" here now replaced "data".

> Here, the **representation** of a Vector (the members elem and sz) [...]

elem and sz are precisely the data members of the Vector class defined in that section:

```
class Vector {
public:
    Vector(int s) :elem{new double[s]}, sz{s} {}   // construct a Vector
    double& operator[](int i) { return elem[i]; }  // element access: subscripting
    int size() { return sz; }
private:
    double* elem; // pointer to the elements
    int sz;       // the number of elements
};
```

**Further Explanation:**
For a concrete type, it is possible from the definition to tell how much memory must be allocated for the data members of an object of this type. When you declare a variable to be of that type somewhere in the source code of your program, the compiler will know its size in memory.
In the case of the class `Vector` defined above, the memory required for the data members of an instance of that class would be whatever memory is needed for an integer `sz` and a pointer to a double `elem`.

An *abstract type* on the other hand, may not specify data members in its definition, so that the memory required for an object of such a type would be unknown.
For more on abstract types see section 3.2.2 of the same book and note that the abstract class `Container` defined in that section has no data members (further supporting my answer to question 1).

With this understanding in mind, some of the exposition that follows the sentence in question where the words *definition* and *representation* are used makes sense. 
I'll paraphrase:
*since the representation is part of the definition of a concrete type, we can place an object of such a type on the stack, in statically allocated memory, and in other objects and we can refer to such objects directly and without the use of pointers or references, etc..*
If we didn't know the size of the data members of an object, we wouldn't be able to do these things.

**In response to question 3:**
I do not know the answer to question number 3, but believe that as stated in previous answers, the terminology used here is informal and shouldn't be viewed as some sort of standard. This goes with the spirit of the part of the book this is written in which is only giving a brief high-level informal overview over C++ not assuming previous knowledge and thus avoiding jargon.